# How to detect tap location in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to print the location (x,y coordinates) of the tapped point in the <#code#> block along with the dimensions of my view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        self.onTapGesture {
            <#code#>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `DragGesture` with `minimumDistance: 0` to your body, example:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack
        {
            
        }
        .frame(
            minWidth: 0,
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            minHeight: 0,
            maxHeight: .infinity,
            alignment: .topLeading
        )
        .background(Color.red)
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onEnded({ (value) in
            print(value.location)
        }))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it prints the tap location. How do I print the frame width and height.

Comment: ```UIScreen.main.bound.size.width``` and ```UIScreen.main.bound.size.height``` will  return width and height of screen size

Answer (score 2):

Starting from iOS 16 / macOS 13, the [`onTapGesture(count:coordinateSpace:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ontapgesture(count:coordinatespace:perform:)-21n4i) modifier makes available the location of the tap/click in the action closure:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .onTapGesture { location in
                print("Tapped at \(location)")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://nilcoalescing.com/blog/GetTapLocationInSwiftUI/